# How to filter JSON using jq on a single field, but display multiple fields?

Tags: json, select, jq

This is the sample data I have. I need to filter on "name" field and print pairs name, url for every name containing "mail":

Source data:

```
 [
     {
         "name": "Yahoo",
         "url": "https://www.yahoo.com/"
     },
     {
         "name": "Yahoo Mail",
         "url": "https://mail.yahoo.com/"
     },
     {
         "name": "Google",
         "url": "https://www.google.com/"
     },
     {
         "name": "Google Mail (Gmail)",
         "url": "https://gmail.com/"
     }
 ]
```

Desired output:

```
Yahoo Mail
https://mail.yahoo.com/
Google Mail (Gmail)
https://gmail.com/
```

How do I do this in jq?

So far this finds all "name" that contains "Mail", but how do I print "url" as well?

```
jq -r '.[].name | select(test("Mail";"i"))'
```

produces output:

```
 Yahoo Mail
 Google Mail (Gmail)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code selects names whereas you want to select parent objects of names. Following yields your desired output.

```
jq -r '.[] | select(.name|test("Mail"; "i"))[]' file
```